# How to sort list without last item

Tags: angularjs

Angular js provide ui:sortable. i just want to apply on whole list item..but don't want drag and drop last item from list. can you please help. how can i come out from this.

I am giving link here

http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/jlkhr

```
<div class="floatleft">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="list">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">
        {{item.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to enable the sort only for certain items:

You add a class 'unsortable' to the items for which the sortable is disabled:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list"
    ng-class="{item: true, unsortable: $last}">
    {{item.text}}
</li>
```

When creating the sortableOptions you specify for which elements the sortable should apply:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    items: "li.item:not(.unsortable)",
    // other options here
}
```

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvxec) is a working example.

Edit:
On [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) documentation you have a list with the properties that could be
used in the condition for applying the 'unsortable' class.
[$index, $first, $middle, $last, $even, $odd]

Comment: Could even use $last as the expression for unsortable in the ng-class.